# How to use Library Methods from another cookbook in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a case where I have to use a library function from another cookbook, but I am always getting `had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method 'func'`.

**What did I try:**

cookbook_1/libraries/lib1.rb:

```rb
module namespace_1
  module namespace_2
    def func(var)
       something
    end
  end
end


Chef::Recipe.include(namespace_1::namespace_2)
```

cookbook_2/metadata.rb:

```rb
.
.
depends 'cookbook_1'
```

cookbook_2/resource/some_resource.rb:

```rb
# Try 1
action :setup do
  a = func('abc')
end

#Try 2
extend namespace_1::namespace_2
action :setup do
  a = func('abc')
end


#Try 3
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, namespace_1::namespace_2)
action :setup do
  a = func('abc')
end


#Try 4
action :setup do
  a = namespace_1::namespace_2::func('abc')
end


#Try 5
Chef::Recipe.include(namespace_1::namespace_2)
action :setup do
  a = namespace_1::namespace_2::func('abc')
end
```

I am getting the same error, i.e. `NoMethodError: undefined method 'func'`
How do I solve this?

Comment: The custom action `:setup` should not be in `metadata.rb`. Or is it in a custom resource?

Comment: corrected it, it was resource @seshadri_c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ruby methods written in libraries or custom resources to be available in custom resource actions, we should use `action_class` block.

Quoting from [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/):

> Use the `action_class` block to make methods available to the actions in the custom resource.

So in your `cookbook1`, apart from having the library, you should have a custom resource with `action_class`. I am giving my own example based on yours.

**cookbook1**: `libraries/lib1.rb`:

```rb
# a custom function to just return the received argument 

module Namespace1
  module Namespace2  
    def custom_func(arg1)
      arg1
    end
  end
end
```

**cookbook1**: `resources/some_resource.rb`:

```rb
property :msg, String, name_property: true

# this is required to make sure functions are available to custom actions
action_class do
  include Namespace1::Namespace2
end

action :setup do
  a = custom_func(new_resource.msg)
  
  log a do
    level :info
  end
end
```

Note that I created the custom resource in the same cookbook as the library. Now this custom resource can be used in `cookbook2`:

**cookbook2**: `metadata.rb`

```rb
depends 'cookbook1'
```

**cookbook2**: `recipes/default.rb`:

```rb
cookbook1_some_resource 'Test custom function'
```