# Chef libraries issue converting from Chef 12 to Chef 14

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Our company is updating to Chef 14 (14.14.25) from Chef 12 (12.19.36).  I have a recipe with a library of helper functions, with this code surrounding it:

```
require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'

module My
  module Helpers
    include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut

     def my_method
       ...
     end
  end
end

Chef::Resource.send(:include, My::Helpers)
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, My::Helpers)
```

These helper methods are then called in a resource in the same recipe, but also may be called from  other recipes (and their resources) that include this recipe.  Hence, as I understand things, why I would want to send to all Chef::Resource's and Chef::Recipe's.  But I should state I am not a Ruby programmer so my understanding is none too deep.

In any case this has worked well with our Chef 12 client, but now breaks with Chef 14, with a NoMethod error for a call to 'my_method'.  (And this in the call to this recipe, not even considering if another recipe is invoking it.)  Here's the full error, with some naming obscured.

```
    NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method `my_method' for #<#<Class:0x0000000003d9fd98>:0x0000000004c56aa8>

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_test_recipe/resources/default.rb:10:in `block in class_from_file'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_test_recipe/recipes/default.rb

     53: call_to_my_resource propertyname
     54:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_test_recipe/recipes/default.rb:53:in `from_file'
```

I've looked at a lot of our other internal recipes, no two are alike and everyone does things differently.  A lot of examples might for instance include the helpers directly in the resource file, but then this would not allow the method to be called directly by other recipes that don't need the resource.  (They do call the resource, but also need to call the helper methods directly.)  Online documentation that explains any of this is scanty.

Comment: To use methods from libraries in resources, they should be included using `action_class` in resource. Please see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464326/13968097) helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works in the particular resources in my same cookbook (in fact had tried it in the first version), but my helper methods are also being called by other recipes/resources not under my control, so it really needs to be included broadly.  I know it's discouraged to do it as I have, but I have high confidence the method names are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research, and based on some hints, I added an additional line:

```
Chef::Provider.send(:include, My::Helpers)
```

This is at the bottom of the helper library file, along with the corresponding "send"s to Resource and Recipe.  I can't say I understand it totally, but am thinking that my custom resource is a Provider class instead of a Resource class?  I would love any comments that can help me understand this better.  I still needed to keep the other lines because of where the helper functions get used.